# awk to parse the ldap data between two strings linux

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

Hi I want to get the strings between two string but in my case the first string like `kdp2002` or `kdp1005` this is not going to be constant for all entries across the output, that means the numbers after `KDP` and always changing and that `KDP`+`number` don't want to be printed.

```
$ ldapsearch -x -LLL -o ldif-wrap=no  -b ou=Projects,ou=People,ou=KDI,o=KDP cn="alltest1p1" KDPHomeDirectory
dn: cn=alltest1p1,ou=Projects,ou=People,ou=KDI,o=KDP
KDPHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=KDI_US-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=KDI,o=KDP#0#Quality=scratch,NisMap=KDP2002:/proj/KDP2002_alltest1p1_scratch_c/q,Quota=20000,Id=scratch_c
KDPHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=KDI_US-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=KDI,o=KDP#0#Quality=economy,NisMap=KDP2002:/proj/KDP2002_alltest1p1/q,Quota=10000
KDPHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=KDI_US-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=KDI,o=KDP#0#Quality=scratch,NisMap=KDP2002:/proj/KDP2002_alltest1p1_scratch/q,Quota=20000,Id=scratch
KDPHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=KDI_US-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=KDI,o=KDP#0#Quality=scratch,NisMap=KDP2002:/proj/KDP2002_alltest1p1_scratch_a/q,Quota=20000,Id=scratch_a
```

**Trial that works Partially:**

```
$ ldapsearch -x -LLL -o ldif-wrap=no  -b ou=Projects,ou=People,ou=KDI,o=KDP cn="alltest1p1" KDPHomeDirectory |  grep -o -P '(?<=NisMap=).*(?=,Quota)'
KDP2002:/proj/KDP2002_alltest1p1/q
KDP2002:/proj/KDP2002_alltest1p1_scratch/q
KDP2002:/proj/KDP2002_alltest1p1_scratch_a/q
```

**Expected output:**

```
/proj/KDP2002_alltest1p1/q
/proj/KDP2002_alltest1p1_scratch/q
/proj/KDP2002_alltest1p1_scratch_a/q
```

Comment: so what you really want is the value of the `NisMap` attribute?  fwiw, when I run your `sed` I get 4 lines of output ... but you've only shown 3 lines of output ... is that a typo (ie, should be 4 lines of output) or are you running a different command from what you've provided?

Comment: @markp-fuso, ah.. sorry that was just copy paste issue, please consider.

Comment: @anubhava, good question but the actual code is having more of awk & sed that grep so, though better use awk or sed.

Comment: @anubhava, also `grep` not working fine as i don't want `KDP2002:` in the output.

Comment: `grep -Po '[^=]*NisMap=KDP[0-9]+:\K[^,]*' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `gnu-grep` you can use:

```bash
grep -oP '=KDP\d+:\K[^,]+'
/proj/KDP2002_alltest1p1_scratch_c/q
/proj/KDP2002_alltest1p1/q
/proj/KDP2002_alltest1p1_scratch/q
/proj/KDP2002_alltest1p1_scratch_a/q
```

Here `\K` resets/discards matched info to give you desired output after `KDP\d+:` only.

---

Alternatively you can use this `gnu-awk` command:

```bash
awk 'match($0, /=KDP[0-9]+:([^,]+)/, a) {print a[1]}' file

/proj/KDP2002_alltest1p1_scratch_c/q
/proj/KDP2002_alltest1p1/q
/proj/KDP2002_alltest1p1_scratch/q
/proj/KDP2002_alltest1p1_scratch_a/q
```

Comment: @ Anubhawa, thanks for the answer +1 and the great explanation with both `grep` & `awk`.

Answer (score 2):

I would harness GNU `sed` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
KDPHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=KDI_US-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=KDI,o=KDP#0#Quality=scratch,NisMap=KDP2002:/proj/KDP2002_alltest1p1_scratch_c/q,Quota=20000,Id=scratch_c
KDPHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=KDI_US-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=KDI,o=KDP#0#Quality=economy,NisMap=KDP2002:/proj/KDP2002_alltest1p1/q,Quota=10000
KDPHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=KDI_US-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=KDI,o=KDP#0#Quality=scratch,NisMap=KDP2002:/proj/KDP2002_alltest1p1_scratch/q,Quota=20000,Id=scratch
KDPHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=KDI_US-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=KDI,o=KDP#0#Quality=scratch,NisMap=KDP2002:/proj/KDP2002_alltest1p1_scratch_a/q,Quota=20000,Id=scratch_a
```

then

```
sed 's/.*KDP2002:\([^,]*\).*/\1/' file.txt
```

gives output

```
/proj/KDP2002_alltest1p1_scratch_c/q
/proj/KDP2002_alltest1p1/q
/proj/KDP2002_alltest1p1_scratch/q
/proj/KDP2002_alltest1p1_scratch_a/q
```

Explanation: I use single capturing group denoted by `\(` and `\)` which containg zero-or-more (`*`) non(`^`) `,`, which is located after `KDP2002:` with whole replacement prefixed by `.*` and suffixed by `.*` to span whole line.

*(tested in GNU sed 4.2.2)*

Comment: @ Daweo, thanks for the answer and great explanation +1,  I am just looking for such a login if i have `KDP2002`, `KDP2003` or `KDP1001` the it could consider that all like of `KDP*` or `KDP\d+`.

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples only, please try following GNU `awk` code.

```
awk -v RS='=KDP[0-9]+:([^,]+)' 'RT{split(RT,arr,":");print arr[2]}' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** With any `awk` version, using `awk`'s `match` function, with your shown samples please try following code.

```bash
awk '
match($0,/=KDP[0-9]+:([^,]+)/){
  split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),arr,":")
  print arr[2]
}
'  Input_file
```